# How do I show all channels I am part of from multiple Slack workspaces?

Tags: slack

We have 2+ workspaces in Slack Enterprise, and I see the shared organizational channels on the two tabs I have open to Slack. However in each tab I see the workspace-specific channels.

I know it's possible to switch Workspaces within one window, but how do I get a list of workspaces and channels?

Or is that only possible in the desktop app? Or am I doomed to keep switching to different tabs for different workspaces?

Answer (score 1):

On the website you can use the [Quick Switcher](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/226599368-How-to-use-the-Quick-Switcher-) to switch between channels on workspaces

Otherwise you **have to download the desktop app**. In the sidebar where channels are listed it also shows another sidebar to the left of that which shows all the workspaces that you are part of:

[image: Slack Mac OS X desktop app]

In the screenshot above you can see that there are 6 workspaces in the sidebar.

Shared channels appear in the channels list under *"Organization Channels"*